# Retrieve response and do an action in a HttpWebRespo call, from an IAsyncResult function C#

Tags: c#

From my class I call another class that makes a call to an API with an IAsyncResult function that listens when the server responds.

My question is how do I go about when the API responds, take that response and do an action.

My code listens, and grabs the answer, but I'm not managing to do anything with it

winForm.cs:

```
var response = services.postService(payment,url);
//if response Its OK make somthing
```

service.cs

```
  public HttpWebRequest request;

  private static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

  public void postService(PayModel paymentObject, String url)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url + "pay");
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "POST";

        var response = request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(result => GetRequestStreamCallback(result, paymentObject)), request);
    }

    public void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult,PayModel paymentObject)
    {
        request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult)))
        {
            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(paymentObject);
            Console.Out.WriteLine(json);
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        var response = request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);



    }

    private void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
        Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
        string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(responseString);
        streamResponse.Close();
        streamRead.Close();
        response.Close();
        allDone.Set();
        frmVenta.closeTransaccion();
    }
```

I tried many things but I can't get the answer, when I put a return on it, it never performs the action, the program continues and does not return

I cant use HttpClient , the program es older.

Comment: I suggest you use HttpClient instead.  Much simpler and cleaner

Comment: Are you limited to a particular version of .NET?  If so you might want to consider the newer `async/await` approach than the older `IAsyncResult` and associative HTTP clients

Comment: .net Framework 3.0, dont work async await :v